# ctypes.util find_library() couldn't find the .dylib

Tags: python, path, ctypes, dylib, fluidsynth

I want to use a python package called mingus, but it couldn't find the FluidSynth library. However, I have already installed fluidsynth using homebrew (I'm using macOS Catalina), and it sits in the directory /usr/local/Cellar/fluid-synth/2.1.8/lib

The error messages are:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6003c50a6278> in <module>
----> 1 from mingus.midi import fluidsynth

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mingus/midi/fluidsynth.py in <module>
     39 import wave
     40 
---> 41 from mingus.midi import pyfluidsynth as fs
     42 from mingus.midi.sequencer import Sequencer
     43 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mingus/midi/pyfluidsynth.py in <module>
     39 )
     40 if lib is None:
---> 41     raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
     42 
     43 _fl = CDLL(lib)

ImportError: Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.
```

The code around line 41 in pyfluidsynth.py is:

```
from ctypes.util import find_library

import six

lib = (
    find_library("fluidsynth")
    or find_library("libfluidsynth")
    or find_library("libfluidsynth-1")
)
if lib is None:
    raise ImportError("Couldn't find the FluidSynth library.")
```

But I have installed the library in

```
>> ls -l /usr/local/Cellar/fluid-synth/2.1.8/lib/
total 688
-r--r--r--  1 hqchen  admin  350160 Apr 13 23:12 libfluidsynth.2.3.8.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hqchen  admin      25 Mar 15 14:12 libfluidsynth.2.dylib -> libfluidsynth.2.3.8.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 hqchen  admin      21 Mar 15 14:12 libfluidsynth.dylib -> libfluidsynth.2.dylib
```

I think my problem roots on how to add search path in find_library? I have tried to add the path in LD_LIBRARY_PATH and LIBRARY_PATH, but neither works. I appreciate any help!!

Comment: `os.add_dll_directory("/usr/local/Cellar/fluid-synth/2.1.8/lib")` before *find\_library*? Note that it might one of its dependencies that's not found.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.I tried and it said " module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory'  "..... sad

Comment: Sorry, it's not present in *v3.7*. How did you set *LD\_LIBRARY\_PATH*?

Comment: I simply set it in the terminal: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/Cellar/fluid-synth/2.1.8/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"

Comment: Try same thing with *DYLD\_LIBRARY\_PATH*. Also check its dependencies (use *otool*).

Comment: I tried, but still didn't work... Also I used otool -tvV libfluidsynth.dylib and it printed out more than 4000 lines and I don't understand

Comment: Try: `otool -L libfluidsynth.dylib` (maybe post the output in the question, if it's not too big).

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I am currently facing it, too.

Comment: Unfortunately no...